# tagger metrics with spacy project run evaluate

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

I'm mostly following the example spacy project [tagger_parser_ud](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines/tagger_parser_ud).

This project trains a tagger and the training output shows the tagger accuracy.

When I run `spacy project run evaluate`, I get detailed metrics for morphology and LAS, but I only get summary information for the tagger.  Is it possible to get per-tag metrics for the tagger as well?

My output is below.

```
$ spacy project run evaluate

================================== evaluate ==================================
Running command: /Users/joneill/.virtualenvs/pb-spacy3/bin/python -m spacy evaluate training/model-best corpus/dev.spacy --output training/metrics.json
ℹ Using CPU

================================== Results ==================================

TOK      100.00
TAG      95.13 
POS      95.65 
MORPH    96.57 
UAS      87.03 
LAS      84.39 
SENT P   97.34 
SENT R   96.95 
SENT F   97.15 
SPEED    15925 


============================== MORPH (per feat) ==============================

                 P        R        F
Definite     99.95    99.99    99.97
PronType     99.89    99.56    99.73
Degree       93.53    91.48    92.49
Number       96.01    95.90    95.95
PunctType    99.91    99.07    99.48
Aspect       89.66    95.20    92.35
Tense        94.74    95.92    95.33
VerbForm     91.12    92.25    91.68
Mood         99.76   100.00    99.88
Person       94.86    91.30    93.05
ConjType     99.94    99.32    99.63
NumType      97.90    98.52    98.21
Polarity    100.00   100.00   100.00
Case         63.64    19.44    29.79
PunctSide   100.00    90.55    95.04
Gender      100.00    34.09    50.85
Poss        100.00    95.24    97.56
Foreign     100.00    33.33    50.00
Reflex        0.00     0.00     0.00


=============================== LAS (per type) ===============================

                 P       R       F
det          96.00   96.05   96.03
amod         83.65   83.89   83.77
nsubj        74.03   68.13   70.96
root         70.71   70.43   70.57
dobj         84.25   83.03   83.64
acl          75.27   84.07   79.43
prep         90.76   90.85   90.81
pobj         92.52   93.11   92.81
advmod       90.30   88.21   89.25
nsubjpass    82.56   82.56   82.56
auxpass      98.63   99.39   99.01
relcl        68.40   71.12   69.74
aux          98.13   96.82   97.47
xcomp        77.42   85.01   81.04
advcl        41.62   33.19   36.93
cc           76.58   76.63   76.61
conj         66.05   66.08   66.07
pcomp        89.83   78.13   83.57
prt         100.00   37.93   55.00
mark         84.88   82.49   83.67
acomp        90.28   91.55   90.91
compound     77.78   83.81   80.68
ccomp        56.97   53.51   55.19
nummod       92.27   91.33   91.79
dep          16.67   24.14   19.72
neg          97.22   97.22   97.22
appos        46.79   44.52   45.63
csubjpass     0.00    0.00    0.00
agent        96.72   97.79   97.25
dative        0.00    0.00    0.00
oprd         70.83   68.00   69.39
attr         88.89   90.00   89.44
quantmod     92.68   79.17   85.39
csubj         0.00    0.00    0.00
nmod         37.04   17.78   24.02
npadvmod     60.83   59.59   60.21
poss         90.91   83.33   86.96
predet        0.00    0.00    0.00
case        100.00   50.00   66.67
parataxis     0.00    0.00    0.00
intj          0.00    0.00    0.00
meta         48.15   43.33   45.61
preconj      75.00   75.00   75.00
expl          0.00    0.00    0.00

✔ Saved results to training/metrics.json
```